# Mongo Sort By Formula

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Is there anyway in Mongo to do a sort based on the sum of two fields. For example if I have a document:

```
doc = {'_id':1,'a':1,'b':2}
```

I would want to do a sort on:

```
doc['a']+doc['b']
```

using something along the lines of:

```
db.collection.find().sort(a+b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$project: {_id: 1, sum_ab: {$add: ["$a","$b"]}}}, 
  {$sort: {sum_ab: 1}}
);
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) and respective parent chapters if needed.

You will have to add all fields you want to the `$project` document

---

Edit: tried and corrected